# Hide pseudo element on click

Tags: css, wordpress, onclick, pseudo-element, pseudo-class

On my wordpress site I have a button on the home page that loads more posts.  I wanted to add a little upside down caret next to the words "load more posts" so I added a "v" using pseudo elements.  I've gotten it to look how I want it to, but when I press the button the v doesn't disappear with the rest of the button?  I have tried fixing it with an ::active class but it still appears. What do I have to do to make it disappear?

example of button

[image]

after button click (I don't want the v to appear)

[image]

current css code

```html
.elm-button::before {
    content: "v"; 
    font-size:11px;
    float: right;
    margin: 6px 0 0 14px;
    font-family: 'Days One', sans-serif;
}
.elm-button::active {
display: none;
    visibility: hidden; 
}
```

Comment: Try with :focus; .elm-button:focus::before.

Comment: Unfortunately the "v" has just disappeared completely if I use .elm-button:focus::before

Comment: @user6738171 I thought you want the v to disappear. What do you actually want?

Comment: Well, you can add the 'v' with a span element.

Comment: The "v" doesn't show up at all.  It doesn't appear next to "load more posts"

Answer (score 0):

There is an error in your snippet. `:active` is a pseudo-class, not a pseudo-element, so it has only one colon.
So, how's this.

```css
.elm-button {
  background:none; border:none; font:inherit;
 }
.elm-button::before {
    content: "v"; 
    font-size:11px;
    float: right;
    margin: 6px 0 0 14px;
    font-family: 'Days One', sans-serif;
}
.elm-button:active {
display: none;
    visibility: hidden; 
}
```

```html
<button class="elm-button" type="button">Load more posts</button>
```

(Also, I presume you need `.elm-button:focus` as well, but that isn't very clear from the problem description.)

Comment: Unfortunately, the above code did not work.  How do you suggest I use  .elm-button:focus?  I tried replacing :active with :focus but still no results.

Comment: You should show more code then. What you gave in the question was not complete, so I had to improvise.

Comment: That is all the code.  The only other code I have is load_more_button(); where I want to place the load more button.  The button is run through a plugin, so there is little code.

Answer (score 0):

### UPDATE

I just realized the same answer was given [before](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41216627/9714920). It did not work for OP for some reason. Here is another approach from [W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_variables.asp), and this gives you more freedom to control each one separately (the css and its pseudo).

```js
var clickedToLoad = false;
$('.elm-button').on('mousedown',
    function(){
      document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--before-display', 'none');
    }
  )
$(document).on('mouseup',
    function() {
      document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--before-display', 'block');
    }
);
```

```css
:root {
  --before-display: block;
}
.elm-button {
  display: var(--before-display);
}
.elm-button:before {
  content: "v";
  float: right;
  margin-left: 6px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<BUTTON class="elm-button">LOAD MORE POSTS</BUTTON>
```

---

### Original Answer

To be clear, you can not change a CSS pseudo elements using JS or JQuery. However, there are other options. Please refer to this previous question

But, your case is much easier, as you can simply change a typo in your code (added double dots before the `active` keyword):

```css
.elm-button::before {
  content: "v"; 
  font-size:11px;
  float: right;
  margin: 6px 0 0 14px;
  font-family: 'Days One', sans-serif;
}
.elm-button:active {
  display: none;
  visibility: hidden;
}

/* Added only to match your output*/

.elm-button {
  background: inherit;
  border: none;
}
```

```html
<BUTTON class="elm-button">LOAD MORE POSTS</BUTTON>
```